# Table caption align top-right

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

How I can align caption for table like this?

[image]

Current code:

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|l|}
        \hline
        № & X     & Y     & Время выполнения м:сс \\ \hline
        1 & 15000 & 16000 & 0:57                  \\ \hline
        2 & 16000 & 17000 & 0:19                  \\ \hline
        3 & 17000 & 18000 & 0:10                  \\ \hline
        4 & 18000 & 19000 & 0:03                  \\ \hline
        5 & 19000 & 20000 & 0:02                  \\ \hline
        6 & 20000 & 21000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
        7 & 60000 & 61000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirement for traditional `\caption` right/left justification implies that the table be boxed. You can do this with [`ctable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable) and [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=off}
\begin{document}
\ctable
  [caption={Some caption}]% <options>
  {|l|r|r|l|}% <column spec>
  {}% <footnotes>
  {% <table>
    \hline
    No & X     & Y     & Hours:Minutes \\ \hline
    1 & 15000 & 16000 & 0:57                  \\ \hline
    2 & 16000 & 17000 & 0:19                  \\ \hline
    3 & 17000 & 18000 & 0:10                  \\ \hline
    4 & 18000 & 19000 & 0:03                  \\ \hline
    5 & 19000 & 20000 & 0:02                  \\ \hline
    6 & 20000 & 21000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
    7 & 60000 & 61000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
  }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `\ttabbox` and `\FBwidth` commands from the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package to get a caption with a width equal to the table width, and then perform an adjustment to the caption justification with the help of the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{floatrow,caption}

\begin{document}

\ttabbox[\FBwidth]{}{%
  \captionsetup{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=off}
  \caption{}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|l|}
        \hline
        № & X     & Y     & text \\ \hline
        1 & 15000 & 16000 & 0:57                  \\ \hline
        2 & 16000 & 17000 & 0:19                  \\ \hline
        3 & 17000 & 18000 & 0:10                  \\ \hline
        4 & 18000 & 19000 & 0:03                  \\ \hline
        5 & 19000 & 20000 & 0:02                  \\ \hline
        6 & 20000 & 21000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
        7 & 60000 & 61000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can use `caption` in combination with the `threeparttable` package. While `threeparttable`'s main function is to allow for table notes, it also restricts the caption width so that it can properly be aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \captionsetup{justification=raggedleft,singlelinecheck=false}
        \caption{}      
        \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|l|}
            \hline
            № & X     & Y     & Время выполнения м:сс \\ \hline
            1 & 15000 & 16000 & 0:57                  \\ \hline
            2 & 16000 & 17000 & 0:19                  \\ \hline
            3 & 17000 & 18000 & 0:10                  \\ \hline
            4 & 18000 & 19000 & 0:03                  \\ \hline
            5 & 19000 & 20000 & 0:02                  \\ \hline
            6 & 20000 & 21000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
            7 & 60000 & 61000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}    
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

One could use `\captionbox` offered by the `caption` package (since version 3.2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{position=t,justification=raggedleft,slc=off}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \captionbox{\label{table1}}{%
        \begin{tabular}{|l|r|r|l|}
            \hline
            No & X     & Y     & Test \\ \hline
            1 & 15000 & 16000 & 0:57                  \\ \hline
            2 & 16000 & 17000 & 0:19                  \\ \hline
            3 & 17000 & 18000 & 0:10                  \\ \hline
            4 & 18000 & 19000 & 0:03                  \\ \hline
            5 & 19000 & 20000 & 0:02                  \\ \hline
            6 & 20000 & 21000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
            7 & 60000 & 61000 & 0:01                  \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately I did not found the time to document `\captionbox` yet, but its syntax is identical to `\subcaptionbox` which is documented in the `subcaption` package documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `captionbox`, `threeparttable`, etc., simply include `singlelinecheck=false` with `justification=RaggedLeft` or `justification=raggedleft` and choose any of `plain/hang` for `format` if not stisfied yet. More probably, `format=plain` is proper for publications standards in Russia.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, justification=RaggedLeft}
```

Take into account, caption may be placed up to end of right border and turn out of table, when narrow table is centered.