# Table caption to the left or right of table

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I am unable to find a method to place the caption of a table to the right or left of this specific table. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in plain TEX or Koma Script (eventually in conjunction with the tabularx environment)?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57108/31034

Comment: I am not referring to justification of the caption above or below a table. I am referring to placing the caption text on the left side of a table, sensu the Koma Script \captionbeside command. I cannot get this command to work for tables, hence my question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the floatrow package: choose something like

```
 \floatsetup{capbesideposition={center,left}}
```

in the preamble, and use this syntax for a particular figure to have a side caption:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
   \fcapside{\caption{Test for side caption}\label{sic}}
   {\includegraphics{myfigure}}
\end{figure}
```

See § 1.1.1 and §§ 3.1.3 to 3.1.7 of the doc for further details about captions.

Comment: +1 if you can show how that works for a table rather than a figure, per the OP.

Comment: @jvriesem: How do you know I'm still alive?

Comment: I don't, of course. I'll give +1 to your account, however, if you---or whatever person/robot/entity controls your account---make the change I suggested. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From the `floatrow` documentation, `\fcapside` macro is an abbreviation for `\floatbox[\capbeside]{figure}`. Try putting the longer form one in directly:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\floatbox[\capbeside]{table}{\caption{This should have the right label}\label{...}}
{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    ...
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).